# How do I write a test class for master-detail relationship that has trigger-based validation of group membership?

Tags: unit-test, master-detail, runas

In my org, I have a pair of objects with a master-detail relationship set up and some trigger-based validation as follows:-

- Both objects contain a picklist field, *Business_Segment__c*
- Both objects have Before Insert/Update triggers that check the
  current user's group membership (via a call to a Trigger Handler class) to determine whether they're entitled to the selection made in the picklist

When it comes to writing test code for the trigger handler, I've managed to cover the Master object tests by creating the necessary Group and GroupMember objects.  As part of a mixed DML operation in the test class, these system objects are created under a System.RunAs(user) context.

For the detail object though, I'm struggling - to test the validation of the detail object independently of the parent Master, I need to ensure group membership for creating the parent, but not for the children.

As per testing best practice, I need to cover both positive and negative flows, so I need to test the outcome of the validation with and without the group memberships in place.  Unfortunately, the RunAs trick doesn't cover the subsequent removal of the groups I set up for the parent object, because it sees the running user as yet another User() instance.

What solutions exist for resolving this?

Comment: Break up your tests for the specific scenarios. Don't try to do it all in one big method. Also, you can wrap multiple blocks in RunAs so that should not be an issue

Comment: or, use Selector layer pattern from Separation of Concerns and mock the selector's results using https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/12/03/mocking-soql-sub-select-query-results/ technique. This way, you don't have to DML insert Groups or GroupMembers at all!